# How do I make a multi-tab homepage in Safari (like Firefox)?

Tags: safari

In Firefox, I've set my homepage to three websites, so that when I open Firefox, it loads them in three tabs.  Is there a way to make Safari open several tabs on startup as well?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a feature that is missing and will probably appear in later iterations.

There are several work arounds that I have come across.

[Workaround 1](http://blog.cortland.edu/techinfo/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/Safarimultiplehomepages.pdf)

[workaround 2](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-applications-games/69572-multiple-tabs-open-safari-launch-ala-firefox.html)

Here is possibly the best from [mac forums](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=185213) & [mac forums](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-applications-games/229498-safari-multiple-tabs-homepage.html):

Create a folder in your bookmarks called "open" - or any other name.
Place your urls in that folder.
Go to preferences and select "New windows open with:"
select "choose tabs folder"
select your "open" folder
Exit Safari
When you open it again your home page tabs should be there!

Comment: I think you contradicted yourself... The method you explain at the end is exactly the feature you claim to be missing at the beginning of your answer! Upvoted regardless, they must have added the feature recently and I didn't know about it.

Comment: I think it is a workaround as opposed to an actual "feature", if you get me.  Once it works, good enough.